# How to build OpenSMILE in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ubuntu

I downloaded openSMILE 2.1.0, and followed the instructions :

> Build the core from source on Linux: run the script buildStandalone.sh
>   (requires automake and autoconf and build-essentials - gcc, g++, make,
>   libtool - to be installed),

I installed the relevant packages, gave permission to `buildStandalone.sh` as executable, and executed it from the terminal. The output is :

```
me@me-EasyNote-TM85:~$ '/home/me/Desktop/openSMILE-2.1.0/buildStandalone.sh' 
chmod: cannot access ‘configure’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘autogen.sh’: No such file or directory
/home/me/Desktop/openSMILE-2.1.0/buildStandalone.sh: line 33: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
/home/me/Desktop/openSMILE-2.1.0/buildStandalone.sh: line 34: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
./configure --prefix=/home/me/inst --enable-static --enable-shared=no
/home/me/Desktop/openSMILE-2.1.0/buildStandalone.sh: line 46: ./configure: No such file or directory
failed to configure openSMILE!
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it to proceed building OpenSMILE?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the ~ in `... TM85:~$`, It looks like that you stand in your home directory. Try `cd /home/me/Desktop/openSMILE-2.1.0/` followed by `./buildStandalone.sh`.